# При подключении к базе данных Access, возникает ошибка

Tags: python, python-3.x, odbc

Я только недавно начал изучать программирование и в колледже задали создать простое окно авторизации при помощи MC Access и Python, используя библиотеки tkinter и pyodbc.
При попытке подключения возникает ошибка:

pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', "[HY000] [Microsoft][Драйвер ODBC Microsoft Access] Не удается найти файл '(нет данных)'. (-1811) (SQLDriverConnect); [HY000] [Microsoft][Драйвер ODBC Microsoft Access] Не удается найти файл '(нет данных)'. (-1811)")

Смотрел форумы, но так и не нашёл ответа на свой вопрос.
Можете, пожалуйста, помочь с этой проблемой и объяснить причину её возникновения.

Код:

```
import pyodbc

table_name = 'NameAndPassword'
conn_str = (
    r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
    r'DBQ=C:\Users\nozex\OneDrive\Документы;'
    )
conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
cur = conn.cursor()
for table_info in cur.tables(tableType=table_name):
    print(table_info)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Извините. Буду иметь ввиду, что так делать не стоит

Comment: А файл называется просто "Документы" без расширения?

Comment: О Боже. Извините, что потратил ваше время из-за этой глупой ошибки

Comment: Да всё нормально, всяко бывает )  Винда сама много где пишет названия файлов без расширения, не мудрено про них забыть вообще

Comment: Спасибо огромное за помощь